# How to instantiate objects given a Class name and a base Namespace

Tags: c#, reflection, instantiation

I'm deserializing DTO objects in run time. And i've used the code below to instantiate objects given a **namespace** and a **type name**

```
public class SimpleDtoSpawner : DtoSpawner{
    private readonly Assembly assembly;
    private readonly string nameSpace;

    public SimpleDtoSpawner(){
        assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (GenericDTO));

        //NOTE: the type 'GenericDTO' is located in the Api namespace
        nameSpace = typeof (GenericDTO).Namespace ; 

    }

    public GenericDTO New(string type){
        return Activator.CreateInstance(
            assembly.FullName, 
            string.Format("{0}.{1}", nameSpace, type)
            ).Unwrap() as GenericDTO;
    }
}
```

This implementation worked for me, when all **Commands and Events** were in the ***Api*** namespace.
But after i separated them into two namespaces: ***Api.Command*** and ***Api.Event***, i need to instantiate them without an exact namespace reference.

Comment: *Why* can't you specify the *correct* full namespace?

Comment: The parameter for New(string type) method contains only the  type Name (not FullName of the Type to be instantiated). This type might be either a Command or an Event. So, given that info i can assert that the 'base' namespace is 'Api' for sure, but the correct(exact) Ns will be either 'Api.Command' or 'Api.Event'. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do something like this:

```
public class SimpleDtoSpawner : DtoSpawner{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Type> types;

    public SimpleDtoSpawner() {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (GenericDTO));
        string baseNamespace = typeof (GenericDTO).Namespace ; 
        types = assembly.GetTypes()
                        .Where(t => t.Namespace.StartsWith(baseNamespace))
                        .ToDictionary(t => t.Name);
    }

    public GenericDTO New(string type) {
        return (GenericDTO) Activator.CreateInstance(types[name]).Unwrap();
    }
}
```

That will go bang when creating the dictionary if you have more than one type under the same "base namespace" with the same simple name. You might also want to change the filter to check whether the type is assignable to `GenericDTO` too.